# Pandas: Why does slice(0,5) work, but slice(0,-1) does not?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Consider the Series data2:

```
data2.head()

0    20075E,
1    20109C,
2    202217,
3    20219E,
4    20217C,
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

The code:

```
data3 = data2.str.slice(0,5)
data3.head()
```

Works just fine, and produces:

```
0    20075
1    20109
2    20221
3    20219
4    20217
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

But running

```
data3 = data2.str.slice(0,-1)
```

Appears to do nothing. Why?

Comment: It does, it chomps off the last character, so it will produce `20075` instead of `20075E`.

Comment: If you want to remove the last two characters, you can use `data2.str.slice(0,-2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: You probably didn't notice that the last character in your records is `,`

Comment: Michael, I did not. Thanks!